# Is it possible to change discord folder name in appdata?

Tags: discord

Mainly asking this for security.

I'm tired of triple-checking everything for so called "token grabbers", and I'm not in the mood to fall for one of them.

Knowing how extremely easy it is from my account to get compromised, I wanna know if there's a way to change discord folder name in %appdata% (not just rename the folder, but also pass that change throughout discord files). Or, if possible, change only Local Storage/leveldb folder name, which is where my user token is stored.
So that way, discord token stealers wouldn't work on my machine as they would search for a token where it doesn't exist.

Would this be possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, but you must change every Discord folder + Startup and every string that Discord use. (unpack & repack core asar etc...)
The best way for protect that is to cancel requests containing discord token regex match.
About local storage, you can clear it during discord opened...

CSharp Sample Code:

```cs
foreach (var item in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("local storage path"))
{
         try {
                  File.WriteAllText(item, "");
         }
         catch{
         }

}
```